# Error in `setDT` from `data.table` package

Tags: r, data.table, environment

It seems like `setDT` returns an error whenever you are trying to run it on a stored data in the `datasets` package. For example

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CO2)

## Error in assign(name, x, parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE) : 
##   cannot change value of locked binding for 'CO2'
```

The strangiest thing is that if you rerun `setDT(CO2)` it will work

So I've looked in the source code of `setDT` and tried to reproduce the error

```
x <- CO2
name <- as.character(substitute(x))
assign(name, x, parent.frame(), inherits = TRUE)
```

Which worked and didn't return any error. My guess is that the `parent.frame()` is the one that causing it, but I can't figure out by myself whats going on back stage. Also, I can't understand why `setDT(CO2)` doesn't return an error on the second run.

My `sessionInfo()`

```
## R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
##   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
##   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
##   [1] data.table_1.9.2
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##   [1] plyr_1.8       reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.3
```

Comment: Filed [bug #5661](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5661&group_id=240&atid=975).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [commit 1320](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/39e89521260d4d696e6befb82f922c692e1cb5ef), `setDT` now returns a friendly error that the object can not be modified by reference when it's binding is locked. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md), No:37 under bug fixes for 1.9.3:

> `setDT` now provides a friendly error when attempted to change a variable to data.table by reference whose binding is locked (usually when the variable is within a package, ex: CO2). Closes [#475](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/475). Thanks to David Arenburg for filing the report [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361080/error-in-setdt-from-data-table-package) on SO.