# Pass parameter to lapply as variable name in data.table

Tags: r, function, data.table, lapply

I'm trying to pass an argument to a function using lapply in datatable, only the argument is a variable name (It is called in a function). The wtd.var function is from Hmisc.
Example using iris:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(data.table)
iris <- as.data.table(iris)
weights.v ="Sepal.Length" 
iris[,lapply(.SD,wtd.var,weights=weights.v),by = "Species"]
```

throws an error, naturally since because the variable is a string. I tried various combinations or paste0 and parse, but get() seems to do it-

```
iris[,lapply(.SD,wtd.var,weights=get(weights.v)),by = "Species"]
```

That works. But when I try to use .SDcols, it gets ignored

```
iris[,lapply(.SD,wtd.var,weights=weights.v),by = "Species",.SDcols=c("Petal.Length")]
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: @docendodiscimus `setDT(iris)` won't work...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, feel free to correct it so it _will_ work

Comment: @DavidArenburg, and on my session it did seem to work - why shouldn't it?

Comment: @docendodiscimus because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361080/error-in-setdt-from-data-table-package) it is very strange it worked for you. It doesn't work for me and this is documented behaviour (as per Aruns answer).

Comment: @DavidArenburg, well, I don't any single error message and iris prints just fine (as data.table) afterwards..

Comment: @docendodiscimus what `data.table` version do you have?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, 1.9.5

Comment: @docendodiscimus very odd. It should only work if you already created a copy of it once. If you'll try it on a fresh session is still works?

Comment: This works: `iris[,lapply(.SD[,"Petal.Length",with=FALSE],wtd.var,weights=get(weights.v)),by = "Species"]`

Answer (score 0):

A simple (but probably sub-optimal) workaround would be to sapply by subsets...

```
sapply(levels(iris$Species), function(x) {with(subset(iris,
Species==x),wtd.var(Petal.Length,Sepal.Length))})
```

Hope this helps.