# setDT() has unexpected side effect

Tags: r, data.table

This question is not a duplicate of [Error in `setDT` from `data.table` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361080/error-in-setdt-from-data-table-package).

```
library(data.table)
dt <- iris
str(iris) # a data.frame solely
setDT(dt)
str(iris) # data.frame and data.table
```

Why should `setDT()` act on an object that is not its argument?

*Thank you all for pointing out **why** iris is changed in parallel with dt. Unless one knew the answer already, there would be no way to know that the question was a duplicate.*

Comment: Related (*dup*): [When should I use setDT() instead of data.table() to create a data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41917887/when-should-i-use-setdt-instead-of-data-table-to-create-a-data-table)

Comment: Related-ish: [Understanding exactly when a data.table is a reference to (vs a copy of) another data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another)

Answer (score 4):

Your objects `iris` and `dt` have the same address in memory. You can make a real copy by `dt <- data.table::copy(iris)`.

Consider this:

```
dt <- iris
> tracemem(iris) == tracemem(dt)
[1] TRUE
```

but

```
dt <- data.table::copy(iris)
> tracemem(iris) == tracemem(dt)
[1] FALSE
```

***Reason***

`?data.table::setDT` says:

> When working on large lists or data.frames, it might be both time and memory consuming to convert them to a data.table using as.data.table(.), as this will make a complete copy of the input object before to convert it to a data.table. The setDT function takes care of this issue by allowing to convert lists - both named and unnamed lists and data.frames by reference instead. That is, the input object is modified in place, no copy is being made.